# Writing a single file component for vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wrote this page basically my third vue app, and I am also new to js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <title> Third  vue app</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>

         .round-button {
            width:15px;
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align:middle;
           }
           .round-button-circle {
              width: 100%;
              height:0;
              padding-bottom: 100%;
              border-radius: 50%;
              line-height:50px;
              border:1px solid #cfdcec;
              overflow:hidden;
              background: #4679BD;
              box-shadow: 0 0 5px gray;
           }
           .round-button-circle:hover {
              background:#30588e;
           }

           .round-button img {
              display: block;
              width: 90%; // control image size
              padding: 24%; // control image alignment
              padding-right: 50%;
              height: auto;
           }
   </style>
   <script src="static/vendor/vue.js"></script>
   <script src="static/vendor/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="select"><label> Source </label>
    <label>Project</label>
    <select v-model="selected" v-on:change="executeLoader()"># v-bind:disabled="isRunning">
        <option disabled selected>Please Select One</option>
        <!--option></option-->
        <option v-for="n in projects" :value="n">
            {{ n.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <div class="round-button">
        <div class="round-button-circle">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="images/leftarrow.png"  alt="Reload" title="Sync with Gitlab" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div> &nbsp;
    <label>Branch:</label>
    <select v-model="selectedBranch" v-on:change="branchSelecter()">
        <option disabled selected>Select a branch</option>
        <option v-for="b in branches" :value="b">
            {{ b.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <small>{{ message }}</small>
</div>

<script>
function dir(object){
    stuff = [];
    for (s in object){
        stuff.push(s);
    }
    stuff.sort();
    return stuff;
}

new Vue({
   el: "#select",
   data: {
      projects: [],
      branches: [],
      selected: "Please Select One",
      isRunning: false,
      selectedBranch: "Select a branch",
      message: ""
   },
   methods : {
   branchSelecter: function(project){
    msg = "Deploy as " + this.selected.name + "@" + this.selectedBranch.name + "-1";
   this.message = "Project: " + this.selected.name + " Branch: "+ this.selectedBranch.name;
   },
   executeLoader: function(){
            baseMsg = "Project: " + this.selected.name;
            this.message = baseMsg + " pulling branches from gitlab."
         if (!this.selected){
            console.log("Nothing is selected");
            this.branches = []

         } else {
         this.branches = ["master"];
         url = "http://127.0.0.1:5050/api/branches/" + this.selected.id
         console.log(url);
             axios.get(
                 url,
                     {
                     mode: 'no-cors',
                     headers:
                         {
                             'Accept': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                             'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
                         }
                     }
                 )
             .then(response => {
                 this.branches = response.data;
                 if (this.selectedBranch.name == 'undefined'){
                     this.message = baseMsg + " - " + this.selectedBranch;
                 } else {
                     this.message = baseMsg + " Select a branch";
                 }

                 })
              .catch(err => {
              console.log("Axios Error has occurred", err);
              })
            }
         }
      },
   mounted() {
   axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5050/api/projects?namespace=placeholder")
   .then(response => {
           this.selectedBranch = "";
         this.projects = response.data.projects;
      })

   }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know how can this become a single file component for vue, I can pretty much figure out the tempalte and the style part but the script part becomes confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more on [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) here. Single File Components are using `.vue` extension. Those files need compiling with Webpack.

Best way to create an application with Single File Components is by using the [Vue CLI](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). This will generate a boilerplate for your application.

Comment: yes, I tried `vue-cli`, and thats what confused me , becuase I wrote a single page pulling `vue.min.js` and `vue-axios.min.js` and how I wrote is `data` is a key to which stores js object that further stores component level variables . but in the vue-cli I experimented it creates data as a function data(), but my structure is quite similar to the `main.js` file.

Comment: If you read the documentation on SFC you will see that the SFC are using Modern JavaScript with ES2015/16. So yeah, there are some differences but that's just modern javascript. Watch Vuecasts, it's a good course to learn more on Vue.